# oAuth2Permissions for (Azure Resource Manager API: https://management.azure.com)

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Hi guys where can i found the **oAuth2Permissions** list for (*Azure Resource Manager API: https://management.azure.com*).. I found this link(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-... for aAuth2Permession but the link is not valid seems.. 
Actually I’m trying to get an *access_token* with the scope to access the *virtual machines of Azure*.. But i could not get the exact scopes and permissions for Azure Resource Manger.. Thanks in Advance for the reply..

Comment: Please update your question with correct MSDN link.

Answer (score 1):

As Google there are **no permissions** needed to **access resource manager** in **Azure**.
Just register your application in **Azure active directory** in **applications page** in your **login** and you can proceed further and **access the Azure resources**.